# What games save to the Steam Cloud?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Which games (except Torchlight) store the current state of the game to the Steam cloud?

What is the Steam Cloud? 
Steam is Valve's online game purchasing and digital delivery service/platform. Steam Cloud is a fairly new addition to the Steam platform that saves the state for various games to Steam's servers in the "cloud". Depending on the game it can save things like your savegames, character setup, keyboard mappings, options, etc so that any PC that you go to will download all those settings for you and keep them in sync as soon as you log into Steam.

Comment: What is steam cloud?

Comment: Steam technology, stores data like savegames on Valve's servers so you can continue your game on any computer you install Steam on.

Comment: Steam is Valve's online game purchasing and digital delivery service/platform. Steam Cloud is a fairly new addition to the Steam platform that saves the state for various games to Steam's servers in the "cloud". Depending on the game it can save things like your savegames, character setup, keyboard mappings, options, etc so that any PC that you go to will download all those settings for you and keep them in sync as soon as you log into Steam.

Comment: @GAThrawn: i've copied your comment to explain the topic, thanx for that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The full up-to-date list](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=23).

Things to note:

- All Valve games use the Steam cloud.
- The majority of games on that list are indie titles, not AAA games, probably because those titles were written specifically with Steam in mind. Still, there are quite a few [AAA games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5722/what-is-an-aaa-game) there as well.

Comment: "All Valve games use the Steam cloud." - The original Half-Life and Portal don't support Steam Cloud, according to their [store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/70/) [pages](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/). They come in bundles with their respective sequels, and the pages to *those* indicate Steam Cloud is supported, but it can just mean *something* supports it. The link you gave also doesn't list Half-Life and Portal. So I guess *newer* Valve games all use Steam Cloud.

Comment: I am pretty sure Portal uses Steam Cloud... It's from significanly after Steam, it's from the same time as Half Life 2: Episode 2. However, I would not be surprised if Half-Life and other GoldSrc games did not use Cloud.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  One counter-example: ARK Survival Evolved.  Claims to use Steam Cloud, but it absolutely, entirely, completely _doesn't_.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily figure out for a particular game on its Steam page, look under Game Details. If it says Steam Cloud, it'll have your data in the sky.

Comment: Tell that to Studio Wildcard, the devs of ARK Survival Evolved.  (I'm pretty sure they're not alone, although I think it's quite a small group)