# Where are my Saved Games kept, and can I back them up?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm intrigued by *Pillars of Eternity's* Trial of Iron mode (essentially, IronMan mode, in which, to reinforce Permadeath, the game creates only one save file, and deletes all old save files each time a new one is created, as well as on character death).

Thing is, what with the game being so new, I'm a little twitchy about losing my ironman run to some manner of bug. I'd like to be able to keep a backup copy of my save periodically. Y'know, for insurance purposes.

Thing is, I can't figure out where my saves are stored. For that matter, are Trial of Iron saves stored differently, and/or protected against this sort of 'abuse' in some way?

Comment: (Personally, I'm interested in answers for the Mac OS X/Steam version of the game, but answers for Win/Linux ought to get upvoted as well if things are different across platforms.)

Comment: Are you using the steam cloud save feature?

Comment: @GodEmperorDune how do you use steam cloud for saves with Pillars of Eternity? I'm used to games having a toggle between local / steam cloud and i don't see that on the save screen.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I've updated my answer to include info about steam cloud. It's in the properties panel in steam, not on the in-game save screen.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune awesome answer, looks like it was already enabled but i would've had no idea.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am not sure about special things with Trial of Iron saves, but the [official save locations are](https://forums.obsidian.net/blog/7/entry-175-location-of-save-games/):

### Windows

> %USERPROFILE%\Saved Games\Pillars of Eternity
>
> %USERPROFILE% usually is something like C:\Users\your-name-here

### OS X

For Steam, GOG, and DRM-free backer disc versions:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Pillars of Eternity/Saved Games

If you bought Pillars of Eternity from the Apple App Store, your save game directory is located here:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.mpdigital.pillarsofeternity/Data/Library/Application Support/Pillars of Eternity/Saved Games

### Linux

> $XDG_DATA_HOME/PillarsOfEternity/SavedGames
>
> If $XDG_DATA_HOME is not defined, it's stored in ~/.local/share

## Steam cloud saves

The steam cloud saves functionality syncs your local save files with the steam cloud. Modifying your save file outside of steam will likely cause this functionality to pop up a warning message about the cloud and local versions being out of sync the next time you launch the game. You can find more information about the steam cloud in [this gaming.se question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87591/).

It can be enabled/disabled by right-clicking on the Pillars of Eternity game in your library and selecting the "Properties" option, then going to the bottom of the updates tab and checking/unchecking the "steam Cloud Synchronization" box as in the below screenshot.

[image: steam cloud save options]

Comment: I do not have any `~/Library/Application Support/Pillars of Eternity/Saved Games` directory. It seems that saved games are in `~/Library/Containers/com.mpdigital.pillarsofeternity/Data/Library/Application Support/Pillars of Eternity/Saved Games`. Syncing this directory does not make any saved game on the second machine ...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows i know about next locations:

> *%USERPROFILE%\Saved Games\Pillars of Eternity*
>
> *%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SavedGames\Pillars of Eternity*
>
> *%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Pillars of Eternity*

I guess it depends if u have Win 7, Vista or XP, plus it may differ between legal copy and cracked one... I heard in cracked version saves may be somewhere in *%AppData%* folder.