# Can I get my saved data back later if I uninstall a steam game?

Tags: steam

If I uninstall a story mode game from steam will my saved game data will be available if I install the game in the future?

Comment: This depends on the game. Some games uses Steam Cloud Sync to save the save. You can check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87591/222753) for more information about Steam Sync.

Comment: I see now my comment was actually an answer. [I have posted it as such now.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/344687/222753)

Comment: You could also cp the save directory to a GameBackup folder - though this is a manual process

Comment: To add to the answer by @Flater below, just check the game's properties. If it has a cloud save option turn it on, or if it's on check if it mentions anything about "XX/XXMB used" or something. If something is stored already on the cloud save, it's most likely safe to uninstall the game. I would just backup the save files either way to be safe. Check online where they are stored and copy them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on the game.

- Some games store saved into the cloud by default. These will always be available upon reinstall.
- Some games store saves locally, but do not delete them when uninstalling the game. Either the saves remain in the game folder, or they are stored somewhere else (e.g. My Documents). Upon reinstalling *on the same computer*, the saves will be available again. If you want to install the game on another computer, you'll have to copy over the saves (if this works for the specific game).
- Some games could possibly remove all their files upon uninstallation; but I haven't personally encountered this yet.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the game. Some games uses Steam Cloud Sync to save the save. You can check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87591/222753) for more information about Steam Sync.