# How can I restore my Baldur's Gate 2 EE save games from Steam cloud save?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud, baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

According to this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360097/260927) and given the information shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAc0j.jpg), my Baldur's Gate 2 save games should be on Steam cloud.

However, the game doesn't show them... how can I access my Steam cloud saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the option - it is "Enable Cloud Saves" in the Gameplay menu.

[image: Enable Cloud Saves option in the Gameplay menu]

Comment: Enable "Enable cloud save" or what was not intuitive?

Comment: finding this menu wasn't at all intuitive, since a `steam cloud` is hardly part of the game play and there was no indication whatsoever that cloud save were enabled or not

Comment: There are more games with such options. To example, Grim Dawn. Not sure if Terraria cloud saves uses Steam, there you can choose it for each character/world separately. A good indicator of steam cloud functioning is a short delay after you exit game and starting it again. Game status will by "synchronizing" or something during this time.